# Generating list of 2 variables in random repetition interval in range 1 to 3 in Python

Tags: python, r, list, random

I need to generate a random list of "X" and "O" symbols in a spreadsheet for my experiment. The sum should be 200 together (100 X's and 100 O's). There shouldn't be more then three same symbols in a row - I am new the python so i am struggling with. It can be in Python or in R. I am thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
a <- sample(rep(c("X","O"), each = 100), 200, replace = F)

table(a)
X   O
100 100
```

Comment: yes, it is doing the trick, but in a list there are more than just 3 same symbols in a row - i need no more than 3 same symbols following each other

Answer (score 0):

```
import random 

def random_ints_with_sum(n):
    while n > 0:
        r = random.randint(1, 3)
        n -= r
        if (n < 0):
          n += r
        else:
          yield r

def print_chars(num, char):
  for i in range(0,num):
    print(char, end="")

num_o = 100
num_x = 100

list_of_o = list(random_ints_with_sum(num_o))
while True:
  list_of_x = list(random_ints_with_sum(num_x))
  if (len(list_of_o) == len(list_of_x)):
    break


for i in range(0,len(list_of_o)):
  print_chars(list_of_o[i],"O")
  print_chars(list_of_x[i],"X")
```